# Datagrid number sequence

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to loop though a list of number in the datagrid column,(num1)then when a certain number appears(in the example it is 10) it copies that number over to the another column(num2)in the same datagrid.But when I run the code I dont get any errors but nothing happens.Any help appreciated

```
  Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows

        If row.Cells("num1").Value = "10 " Then 
            row.Cells("num2").Value = "10"
        End If
   Next
```

Comment: try removing the space character in 
If row.Cells("num1").Value = "10 "
make it
If row.Cells("num1").Value = "10"

Comment: Hi Mainak 
Many thanks for the reply ,I tried that (and a few variations) but still doesn't work.I have done a similar thing in VBA that works OK,but in that I use the Offset method,but I dont know how to do that in VB.net.